# How to get inbox mail from office 365 in php?

Tags: php, outlook-restapi, outlook-api

I have been attempting to get email's from office 365 using PHP. Here i need to get email's without user login.So i'm trying to get access token without user login.

This is the end point where i'm getting access token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

It's a POST request using following key param values

```
client_id     xxxxxx
scope         https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret xxxxxx
grant_type    client_credentials
```

Then i'm getting response as

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 0,
    "access_token": "xxxxxxxxRiNDcvIiwiaWF0IjoxNTMzMDYwMjA2LCJuYmYiOxxxxx"
}
```

After that i don't know which api to use to get email's from mail box using access token.Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can always just use good old IMAP, see [imap_open()](http://www.php.net/imap_open).

Comment: `imap_open('{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'login', 'passwd')`

Comment: it's possible to get email's from imap_open then parse it to store in DB.

Comment: Of course it is, the only thing IMAP can't do are Exchange features, like synchronizing contacts or modifying recipient rules. Everything related to the emails works.